# Store Jagged array in Defined name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, jagged-arrays

I need to store a jagged array in a defined name, so that it can be saved and the contents referred to on re-opening the workbook.  The code below creates the jagged array beautifully, and in the correct dimensions, but the Names.Add method produces "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".
Hovering over the word 'Name' when debugging the relevant line brings up the clue "Object variable or With block variable not set".  I've tried changing variable names, using the 'Set' statement to transform the Fee3 array into an object, and anything else I could think of.  Please help.

```
Sub GetFee3Codes()
Dim r1 As Integer, r2 As Integer, r3 As Integer, r4 As Integer, r5 As Integer, c5 As Integer
Dim Fee3, UserType, ClientType, StartDate, PayerType, RateOrAmt
ReDim Fee3(1), UserType(1), ClientType(3), StartDate(3), PayerType(14), RateOrAmt(14, 3)
    For r1 = 1 To 1
        Fee3(r1) = UserType
        For r2 = 1 To 1
            Fee3(r1)(r2) = ClientType
            For r3 = 1 To 3
                Fee3(r1)(r2)(r3) = StartDate
                For r4 = 1 To 3
                    Fee3(r1)(r2)(r3)(r4) = PayerType
                    For c5 = 1 To 3
                        For r5 = 1 To 14
                            Fee3(r1)(r2)(r3)(r4)(r5) = RateOrAmt
                        Next r5
                    Next c5
                Next r4
            Next r3
        Next r2
    Next r1
    Names.Add Name:="Fee3", RefersTo:=Fee3, Visible:=True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru a defined name does **not** have to refer to a range. You can put formulas, constants (including 1/2D array constants)

Comment: A defined name has to be something you can store as a formula essentially, and I can't think of any way of representing a jagged array like that in a formula.

Comment: @Rory: I had some time and tried better understanding the Name object. The Microsoft definition for `Names.Add` is "Defines a new name for a range of cells.". And for the `Name Object`: "Each Name object represents a defined name for a range of cells". I would say, exactly what I said in the comment I deleted when you enumerated some other things which a defined name can refer. So, can you show us example(s) not referring a range? A cell returning a UDF function does not count, I would say... :). I really like learning. If not the appropriate place here, some links will be good enough, too.

Comment: @FaneDuru You can define a name that refers to `=1`, or `="some text"`, or `={1,2,3}` for example.

Comment: This is **Not** the source of your problem, but a name like `Fee3` is not a legal name. You cannot have a name that is interpretable as a cell address.

Comment: @Rory: OK. Thanks! Can you post here a code line creating a name referring to something else than a range? To `={1,2,3}` and `=1`, for example. Even `="some text"' would be OK. I'm trying to imagine how to use them, too... Maybe because of the fact that I all the time used cell(s) ranges.

Comment: @ronrosenfeld Thanks for the heads-up re the illegal name.  Missed that one.  I wish it WERE the source of the problem!

Comment: @FaneDuru for example: `Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:="={1,2,3,4}", Visible:=True`

Comment: @DaveGreen could you store the jagged array as a literal JSON string in the named range, then deserialize when you need it?

Comment: @RyanWildry If the Names.Add approach gets a clear thumbs-down from the SO gurus (I'm still clinging to hope), I would certainly consider that.  Any ideas how to make it happen?

Comment: Why save it as a `Name`? Are you going to be accessing it directly from a worksheet somehow?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, the user will display, add +/or change content of the jagged array, using a worksheet interface and index values.  And the rest of the VBA code will access the array content directly, creating lightning-quick processing behind the scenes.  Neat and fast, in concept.  Just needs to be save-able.

Comment: Perhaps you could create the jagged array with the `Workbooks_Open` event, and store it in a global variable.  Then develop your user interface to access that instead of a `Name`

Comment: @Rory: Yes. Thanks! I was trying it in the same way, but keeping "Fee3" name. I did not observed that it can be confused with a cell address...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach I mentioned in the comments. Since you can store text in a named range, you can serialize the array as JSON, then deserialize when you need it. Although, I think just running the method you have on `Workbooks_Open` event would be simpler as Ron Rosenfeld pointed out.

You need to add the VBA JSON project which is referenced in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

'You'll need the VBA JSON Project installed https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
'Also, will need a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime added
Sub AddJaggedArrayAsName()
    'Create an array
    Dim arrayExample As Variant
    ReDim arrayExample(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    
    arrayExample(1, 1) = "A"
    arrayExample(1, 2) = "B"
    arrayExample(2, 1) = "C"
    arrayExample(2, 2) = "D"
    
    'Convert the array to JSON and add to name range
    Dim Json As String
    Json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(arrayExample, Whitespace:=2)
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Something", RefersTo:=Json, Visible:=True
        
    'Parse the JSON back to an object and iterate
    Dim JsonObject As Object
    Dim RefersToString As String: RefersToString = ThisWorkbook.Names("Something").RefersTo
    Dim JsonStringFromNamedRange As String
    
    'Remove starting equal sign and extra quotes
    JsonStringFromNamedRange = Replace(Mid$(RefersToString, 3, Len(RefersToString) - 3), """""", """")
    Debug.Print JsonStringFromNamedRange 'JSON here
    
    Set JsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonStringFromNamedRange)
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    
    'Iterate and show values
    For Each key In JsonObject
        For Each item In key
            Debug.Print item
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, guys.  I'll try those ideas.  And I'll keep monitoring this thread.

Comment: I do not think that such a very big string resulted from the jagged array in the question can be kept by `RefersTo` Name parameter... But it can be easily saved in a text file and read when necessary to make conversion.

Comment: @FaneDuru it's a demo of the concept. If the string becomes very long, just add the text to a `Range` and reference that instead. It can stay in Excel in that case

Comment: I understood that. It is a brilliant idea about transforming such a jagged array in a string (able to be reconverted when needed), which can be saved/used in many ways. I voted it up due to this aspect. I only tried to emphasize that all elements of the jagged array from the question will produce a huge string (probably) not being able to be used when try adding a Name. Even this is a (reasonable) supposition, I did not test it... :)

Comment: I tested the real jagged array back conversion and it looks not being so simple. Anyhow, the way like it is in your demo does not work. The iteration between `JsonObject` elements looks to be much more complicated...

Comment: Huge thanks to all who've responded to my original question.  Each suggested approach has both pros and cons.  My ultimate solution has been to lower my own ambitions, have users store the data in the worksheet, and create an array whenever needed - closest to @Ron Rosenfeld's approach.  But special thanks to Rory, Ryan and Fane for their efforts.